# method executeQuery(string) in the type statement is not applicable for the arguments (), Where am I going wrong? Using Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, string, eclipse, methods

this is my code where I get the problem, following directly from a recorded lecture of mine to catch up on, he has no errors next to his line **but** I do? Curious as to what I'm doing wrong as I am directly copying the code off the screen.

'''

```
public class DisplayAuthors {

// database URL
static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/books";

public static void main ( String args[] ) {
    
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement pstat = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    
    try {
        
        // establish connection to database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "");
        
        // create Prepared Statement for querying table
        pstat = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT AuthorID, FirstName, LastName FROM Authors");
        
        // query database
        resultSet = pstat.executeQuery();
        
        //process query results
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println(" Authors Table of Books Database:\n");
        
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++ ) 
                System.out.print(metaData.getColumnName( i )+ "\t");
                System.out.println();
```

'''

Comment: `Statement pstat` should perhaps be `PreparedStatement pstat`.

Comment: you're a savior, don't even know how I didn't cop that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Statement doesn't have an executeQuery() method, it only has executeQuery(String) - this is what the error is telling you.

PreparedStatement does have executeQuery() but you defined pstat as a Statement instead of PreparedStatement. Change

```
Statement pstat = ...
```

to

```
PreparedStatement pstat = ...
```